# React Router prop changes causing unnecessary render

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am working on an app that has a range of routes that display essentially the same data except the route filters the list based on a status property that determines which entries we want shown in the list.

So in my App.js file I have all the routes set up and the listItems are passed into each of these route components as a property. These items are then rendered out as a table.

Now I have some logic that greys the list out and disabled the buttons on the list items when the list is refreshing using a toggle (isRefreshing) state variable.

The isRefreshing state variable is toggled off using a useEffect() that fires when listItems is updated.

This works great for the refreshing button, but not so well when the route changes.

I've figured out it's because when the route changes the existing listItems prop gets fed into the new rendered list component it see that as listItems changing, so the useEffect() fires, toggling isRefreshing off.

2 seconds later the real data for this new route turns up in the list.

So my question is how can I prevent this from happening? I feel like I might have backed myself into a corner and made a serious architectural error.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I've created an example here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/small-sound-rikxv?file=/src/App.js:0-2353

As you can see the refresh button works as expected, but the route change causes the listItems prop to immediately cause my refresh indicator to stop, so you can see a console.log fired immediately after hitting the "list2" link, then 5 seconds later when the real data loads it fires again. The problem is that the initial prop value causes my refresh to stop.

Regards, John.

Comment: Rendering in react can be challenging topic.  I suggest you post a minimal reproducible example so we can troubleshoot.  Without seeing the code I suggest you add the isRefreshing field as a dependency of the useEffect instead of the array itself.  But it is pure speculation since I have not seen the code.

Comment: Can u share some code? There is alot of things about state and rerendering in react. For example to prevent rerender when function is changed (because of rerender) you can use useCallback. https://infinitypaul.medium.com/reactjs-useeffect-usecallback-simplified-91e69fb0e7a3

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies, I'll add some code right now. Give me 10 mins.

Comment: Simple demo code is here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/small-sound-rikxv

Comment: Oh I think I figured it out. I need to lift the "refreshing" state up to my App.js file, that way I can control the refreshing there and not depend on variables further down the component tree!

Answer (score 0):

So I found that if I lifted the "refreshing" state variable right up to the same component the data fetching was happening in then things got a lot easier for me.

Even though the property value changes twice still, because the refreshing state is being handled further up the tree, with refreshing now getting passed down, it's not an issue.

With refreshing getting managed up the tree, the refreshing toggle only gets toggled when refreshing is actually happening and not when the prop thinks it has changed.

Thanks for getting me to code out a simple example, that really helped me conceptualize what was happening free from the clutter of my app's code base.